# Does JMeter support to select a sampler in Thread Group randomly?

Tags: random, jmeter, threadgroup

In my Test Plan, I have Thread Group with 5 Samplers. Is there a way with JMeter that I want to select **one among the 5 samplers** in Thread Group **Randomly** and do performance testing to only that **particular sampler** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to your Test Plan and create i.e. `randomSampler` variable with the value of `${__Random(0,4,)}` (use [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) to generate a random number between 0 and 4 inclusively)

   [image]
2. Add [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to your Thread Group and use `${randomSampler}` as the "Switch Value"

   [image]
3. Put your Samplers under the Switch Controller
4. That's it, each time you run the test the random Sampler will be chosen and executed:

   [image]